# How to use Super Grub2 disk *.cfg scripts on partition with installed Grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, wubi, partition-recovery, boot-partition

How do I use Super Grub2 disk with all its `files.cfg` scripts on a partition which has installed Grub2?

I tried to do a raw copy with `dd` to a partition, but it didn't work – only a raw copy to a whole disk drive (USB pen drive) worked.

So is it possible to run `sg2d` from a partition and not from a whole disk? Or how do I install the whole Super Grub2 disk or something different like Wubi or Grub2, so I can run it from a partition?

Answer (score 1):

I need this too, because my MacBook 2007 version cannot boot from an USB flash drive.

From this guide
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/SGD_Howto_make#Gnu.2FLinux_.28and_being_usable_for_storage_later.29

It apears sg2d relies on MBR boot code thus you would need to backup the boot code of a sg2d drive and the partition table of your harddrive, then merge the two and write it back to the harddrive like the guide shows.

I have not tested this myself. If you choose to do this it is advisable to backup the data of your harddrive. This will overwrite the existing boot code of the harddrive needed for OS's like Windows!